# How do we call a huge building where too many people live

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

Hi, how do you call a huge apartment building where way too many people live? Usually, apartments there are quite small and similar to one another, and infrastructure around is not that developed. You can see what kind of building I mean in the picture
Thanks!

Comment: I think most would just call it a "huge apartment building". The point at which it's considered to have "way too many people" will vary from person to person, so is fairly opinion-based.

Comment: 'Tenement' has a connotation of poor housing and overcrowding, and indeed [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/tenements) lists 'slum' as a synonym – but the overlap is far from complete. I'd stick with a phrasal description.

Comment: An apartment block or complex.

Comment: I like "complex" to indicate a significant structure with apartments in it, but I'd add "mega-" to make it clear that it is an extremely large structure, so "mega-complex" or "apartment mega-complex".

Comment: There's not really a term for it because some large buildings are nice and some are not, and some start out OK but deteriorate. You're probably better with a generic term like slum, favela, project, ghetto.

Comment: The photo is not of a "slum" or "ghetto" as the terms are understood in AmE. *Projects*  is possible.

Comment: "Apartment block" and the like are plain factual terms, and actually a more exact term is "high rise apartment building" or "tower block"; this is not, apparently what the OP is looking for; "too" in "where way too many people live" is the give-away clue. A term with similar characteristics, but which does not apply, is "hive", with its here unwanted connotations of great activity. Another non-applicable term is "dormitory town", which contains some of the connotations (overpopulation, minimum of infrastructure). (wanted, a term of that sort, with more or less negative connotations).

Comment: You really have to define "too many". Your image shows what appears to be quite a modern building, so I doubt too many people live there (especially considering it is likely build according to strict regulations concerning housing).

Comment: An apartment block or an apartment complex.

Answer (score 1):

Such buildings are often called **apartment blocks** as Lambie suggested.

Speakers of American English would understand the phrase to be a close match for  your description and photo. I'm not sure about British English.

**Apartment complex** on the other hand would not necessarily conjure up the same image, as the term is often used for apartment buildings with only two or three storeys and whose buildings have more space between them, and there are often ground-level parking lots and sometimes even a good amount of "green space" --  with grass lawns, shrubbery, and trees, and these complexes can be conveniently located not far from shopping centers, public transportation, schools, and also adjacent to other kinds of dwellings.

Comment: Could 'block of flats' qualify as the British English equivalent?

Comment: @numberfive I'm not the right person to ask but I think yes.

Answer (score -4):

### SUMMARY :

The word OP wants is **"Mansion/Mansions"** , though there are 2 Different & Contradictory meanings here.
One meaning is that it is a set of apartments where multiple families reside.
The other meaning is that it is a grand building where one rich family lives.

### DETAILS :

(1) British English uses the word [Mansion](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780198609810.001.0001/acref-9780198609810-e-4330) :

> a large, impressive house;
> originally (in late Middle English) denoting the chief residence of a lord.
>
> In plural, the word also meant each of a number of separate dwelling places or apartments in a large house or group of buildings;
>
> other than in place-names, this sense is now usually found in biblical allusion to John 14:2,
> ‘In my father's house are many mansions.’... ...

(2) The Asterix Story ["The_Mansions_of_the_Gods"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mansions_of_the_Gods) uses the same word for a large "apartment" where multiple families can reside.

(3) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansion has this :

> In British English, a mansion block refers to a block of flats or apartments
> designed for the appearance of grandeur

(4) BBC lists "unused mansions" here :
https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-30004491

(5) [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/mansion) has this :

> ​Mansions [plural] (British English)
> used in the names of blocks of flats
> Moscow Mansions, Cromwell Road

(6) [Dictionary.Com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mansion) has this :

> a very large, impressive, or stately residence.
> Often mansions. British. a large building with many apartments; apartment house.
> Archaic. an abode or dwelling place.

Comment: "Mansion" is really very wrong indeed.  I don't often downvote but I have here.  Note that when  "mansions" is used in reference to a block of flats/apartments, they are (or were at the time of building) rather grand buildings with quite fancy flats, and it was still marketing exaggeration.  That Oxford Dictionary example still exists and [can be seen on Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Moscow+Mansions,+224+Cromwell+Rd,+London+SW5+0SP/@51.4947464,-0.1949732,3a,75y,336.15h,108.16t)

Comment: In the Answer , I included your meaning about grandness & the other meaning about apartments where many families reside , @ChrisH , while you can see the words "impressive" & "stately" & "grandeur" to match your meaning , you can also see the words "dwelling places or apartments" & "large building with many apartments" & "flats" : Words often have multiple meanings & change meanings gradually too. No worries about downvoting with feedback [ thank you for the feedback ] though there are certain users who follow herd mentality to downvote without reading further.

Comment: Moscow Mansions https://www.google.com/maps/place/Moscow+Mansions,+224+Cromwell+Rd,+London+SW5+0SP,+UK/@51.4947464,-0.1949732,3a,88.3y,341.57h,85.22t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1stb_3FPNHgbkLIzod4MgPtg!2e0!7i16384!8i8192!4m7!3m6!1s0x48760ff3403cc72f:0x4ab50b3e89c8f132!8m2!3d51.4949274!4d-0.1950865!10e5!16s%2Fg%2F1tvrz64v?entry=ttu#

Comment: Compare it with "In plural, the word also meant each of a number of separate dwelling places or apartments" , @TimR , English words often have multiple meanings which might even be Contradictory !

Comment: @Prem  English words can have multiple meanings, true, but this apartment-building meaning of "mansion" doesn't apply to the eight-storey (and taller) buildings described in the question. Nor does it apply to large clusters of such highrise buildings, or to their relative isolation. A mansion apartment building is two or three storeys, is located in the midst of other types of dwellings, is located convenient to shops and transportation and other amenities, has individual apartments that are typically quite spacious, and usually has a facade that is architecturally traditional in appearance.

Comment: Do you have some references to back your claims , @TimR , the references I gave (including Asterix !) do not require such criteria , neither does OP want that !

Comment: Did you visit the link I supplied above?

Comment: Surely , you are not claiming that what google maps shows for the one mansion you gave is representative of all mansions & everything else must match , including wall colours & number of windows & height. Even then , google maps is not listing your criteria about the convenience of shops & transportation. If the government closes all shops & prohibits transportation in that area , will google maps automatically claim it is no longer a mansion ?! What I am asking for , @TimR , is justification references for the criteria you listed , similar to the justification references I gave.

Comment: I could be totally wrong , but I am yet to see the "Proof" of that !!

Comment: Yes, I am claiming that Moscow Mansions is representative of mansions *where the term **mansion**  refers to a building with mutliple apartments*.  If you know of places called "mansions" that resemble the photo and description in the original post, please provide some kind of link.